# How to Use a Global Wait keyword in a test case which will apply for all keywords in ROBOT FRAMEWORK, without writing wait for each keyword

Tags: selenium, testing, robotframework

I want to write a global wait keyword to apply for all keywords in a robot framework file.

```
click element       xpath=//button[@class='btn btn-primary']
sleep       5
click element       xpath=//button[normalize-space()='Get started']
sleep       3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use keyword - `Set Selenium Speed <time>` this will apply running entire suite.

Comment: Just now had a talk with my manager..He is saying it is better to use explicit wait...But how can I declare explicit wait globally for all keywords

Comment: Aforesaid keyword would be a good fir for you. Sets the delay that is waited after each Selenium command.

The value can be given as a number that is considered to be seconds or as a human-readable string like 1 second. The previous value is returned and can be used to restore the original value later if needed.

https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Set%20Selenium%20Speed